# PHP + GridFS: Own id

Tags: php, mongodb, gridfs

I want save many files using MongoDB's GridFS but I ran into some trouble by using my own id. My simplified code is the following:

```
<?php
$mongo = new Mongo();
$db = $mongo->myFiles;
$grid = $db->getGridFS();

var_dump($grid->storeBytes("ForTestingPurposes", array("_id" => new MongoID("mySampleId"), array("safe" => true))));
?>
```

I assumed that storeBytes() returns my own id (in this case "mySampleId") but what I get is something like this:

```
object(MongoId)#5 (1) { ["$id"]=> string(24) "50ae7542a34156852300003d" }
```

.. the automatically generated ID from Mongo. Is there anything wrong with my code above? Thanks for any suggestions...

Answer (score 2):

The PHP [MongoId class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoid.php) is only for working with [MongoDB ObjectIDs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs), which have a specific 12-byte format.

If you want to use a custom value for `_id`, just pass the string directly, eg:

```
$grid->storeBytes("ForTestingPurposes", array("_id" => 'mySampleId', array("safe" => true))));
```

Comment: We should actually check for this value. There is a JIRA ticket for this: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP-554

Comment: Alright, but by using a regular string, I run into some trouble by trying to persist the same ID multiple times... when I call my script the first time and an empty GridFS/MongoDB, everything works fine. By calling the script again and trying to persist the same id again, it also works fine... but why? I think _id must be unique... but my script does not throw anything by persist a file with the same id again... By calling the script again and again and again... I sometime get "Duplicate Error" but sometime not. By list the files of my GridFS after each call, the file was deleted sometimes.